# TypeInitializationException

Tags: .net, file-io, zip, j#, typeinitializeexception

I tried to zip files(ie.images,txt,doc....) in c# and tried [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/neo_matrix/SharpZip04242007001341AM/SharpZip.aspx) (which gives a answer by using `J#`)

```
 using java.io;
 using Java.util.zip;

 \\part of code which throws exception
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Zip(@"D:\Zipped.zip",new string[]{"ico_1.ico","readme.txt"});
    }
 private void Zip(string zipFileName, string[] sourceFile)
    {
      FileOutputStream filOpStrm = new FileOutputStream(zipFileName);
```

Exception message:

`'The type initializer for 'java.io.File' threw an exception.'`

I found that the problem is on `FileOutputStream` .. But, cant find a way to to solve it.. And all i want is a solution to solve this issue and reason for this Exception....

Comment: You will need to document the InnerException and post the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Debug it! Debug the code line by line in IDE, then you can know which line throw this exception.

When a class initializer fails to initialize a type, a TypeInitializationException is created and passed a reference to the exception thrown by the type's class initializer. The InnerException property of TypeInitializationException holds the underlying exception.